# Change the Label on the shop page to display stock quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Right now, my shop only displays only 2 badges on my shop page. Special Offer and out of stock. I would also want to include stock quantity below 10 and Allow for back order. I have looked at multiple plugins as well as php code, but nothing seems to work. What I want to do is display "Only {QTY} Is Available" is the stock drops below 10 and if it is 0 then "available on back order". Website is built in WooCommerce and WordPress

I would like these messages to replace the special offer badge if these conditions are met. I have attached a screenshot below:-

[image]

Any assistance is greatly appriciated

Comment: It looks like your theme has been customised to show the 'Special Offer' badge, and the quantity of stock left. Maybe the actions `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` and `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` are already hooked? Could you please add any existing implementation details to your question?

Comment: Thank for the reply. The 'Special Badge' comes from https://www.flycart.org/products/wordpress/woocommerce-discount-rules. The only other things I have done is activated the stock display format in WooCommerce and added the code to change the back order text

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact two parts to your question: how to change the stock availability text and how to remove the sale badge, when some criteria on the product stock level is met.

Changing the stock availability text should be easily achieved by hooking in the `woocommerce_get_availability` filter. Get the product stock quantity and amend the text accordingly. E.g.:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_override_get_availability', 10, 2 );

function custom_override_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {

  $stock_quantity = $_product->get_stock_quantity();

  if ( 0 === $stock_quantity ) {
    $availability['availability'] = 'Available on backorder';
  } elseif ( $stock_quantity < 10 ) {
    $availability['availability'] = sprintf( 'Only %s available', $stock_quantity );
  } else {
    $availability['availability'] = sprintf( '%s left in stock', $stock_quantity );
  }

  return $availability;
}
```

As for removing the sale badge, I think the plugin you're using provides templates that can be overridden. Have a look in the `Views` folder, you should find the `sale-flash.php` templates. You can then override those templates in your theme and apply a similar logic, as you have access to the `product`. E.g. this shows the sale badge only when the product is on sale and the stock quantity is greater than or equal to 10:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $post, $product;

?>
<?php if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->get_stock_quantity() >= 10 ) : ?>
  <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', '<span class="onsale wdr-onsale">' . esc_html__( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', $post, $product ); ?>
<?php endif;
```

Although I'm not really sure if you want to remove the sale badge when the product stock quantity is less than 10.

Comment: Thank you. I will implement this asap